# Reduce Oracle Query to return just owner

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying to find a simple way to generate a SQL Query as JSON but I'm coming up blank.  This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner 
FROM dba_segments 
WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN');
```

What I want to have this display is json similar to this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "{#Owner}": "ABC123Test"
    }, {
        "{#Owner}": "Accounting"
    }, {
        "{#Owner}": "Treasury"
    }, {
        "{#Owner}": "Production1"
    }]
}
```

In SQL Server I would simply utilize XML PATH and do something like this -

```
SELECT '{"data":[' + (SELECT CAST(STUFF((SELECT ',' + '{"{#Owner}":"' + DISTINCT[owner] + '"}' 
FROM dba_segments 
where owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN') FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS VARCHAR(MAX))) + ']}' as 'XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B'
```

Comment: Note that it should be all uppercase for the macro/variable names, like {#OWNER}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT '{ "data": [{'||listagg('"{#owner}":"'||owner||'"}', ',') within group (order by owner)||'}]}' as json
FROM (
  select distinct owner 
  from dba_segments 
  WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN', 'APEX_040200')
) t;
```

(Not sure if I got the nesting of all the `{` and `[` right)

Comment: I just ran the query and got the following - `'{"DATA":[{'||LISTAGG('"{#OWNER}":"'||OWNER||'"}',',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYOWNER)||'}]}'`

Comment: @whoisearth: well, that's the default name Oracle assigns to an expression (I changed the query to supply a column alias). It should return one row with the JSON data - unless there are no users in your system that match the `where` clause in the derived table. What does `select count(distinct owner) from dba_segments where owner not in (...)` return?

Comment: I'm going to call out my ignorance with oracle.  I ran your updated and it just shows `JSON` but what you're saying is if I were to run it in sql developer it actually is displaying the data?

Comment: the count returns 106 items

Comment: If there are users, then the query **will** display the JSON value (unless the total size is smaller then 4K). Which tool do you use to run the query?

Comment: I'm running the query with isql to test for zabbix which is using odbc.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that isql or zabbix thing is.

Answer (score 1):

Using 12.2.0.1.0 This works (Note I had to use the materialize the WITH clause to get the correct results)

```
SQL> set lines 89
SQL> with DBA_SEGMENT_OWNERS
  2  as
  3  (
  4    select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ DISTINCT OWNER
  5      from dba_segments
  6     where owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT')
  7  )
  8  select JSON_OBJECT('data' is JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('{#Owner}' is OWNER)))
  9    from DBA_SEGMENT_OWNERS
 10  /
{"data":[{"{#Owner}":"MDSYS"},{"{#Owner}":"VPDTEST"},{"{#Owner}":"CTXSYS"},{"{#Owner}":"H
R"},{"{#Owner}":"DVSYS"},{"{#Owner}":"AUDSYS"},{"{#Owner}":"SCOTT"},{"{#Owner}":"VPDOWNER
"},{"{#Owner}":"GSMADMIN_INTERNAL"},{"{#Owner}":"OJVMSYS"},{"{#Owner}":"ORDSYS"},{"{#Owne
r}":"ORDS_METADATA"},{"{#Owner}":"ORDDATA"},{"{#Owner}":"XDBEXT"},{"{#Owner}":"LBACSYS"},
{"{#Owner}":"XFILES"}]}


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want a really big project on your hands, you really don't want to roll your own JSON parser/writer.  For many projects, I've used [PLJSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) which is a library of packages that can manipulate/parse/write JSON inside PL/SQL.  I'm sure there are other options out there as well, but this has performed well for me.

**EDIT**:

Looks like in 12c, Oracle supports JSON.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm) for more.

Comment: The JSON support in Oracle 12 won't help as it only enables to _query_ JSON documents, but no _generate_ them (e.g. like `row_to_json()` or `json_agg()` in Postgres)